# NoMethodError eventhough action is defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I am trying to build a website where a user can book a room. I have a working favorite feature but only if a user is logged in. If a visitor simply wants to view the show.html.erb of a single room I am getting this error:

[image]

I actually have defined favorite.

**How can I make the visitors be able to view the show.html.erb of a single room?**

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :favorite]
...
...

  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @room unless current_user.favorites.exists?(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'You favorited #{@room.listing_name}'
    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@room.listing_name}'
    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end


  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**show.html.erb (room)**

```
<% if current_user.favorites.exists?(@room) %>
   <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_room_path(@room, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_room_path(@room, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

I have a user, room and favorite_room model:

**favorite_room.rb**

```
belongs_to :room
belongs_to :user
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :favorite_rooms # just the 'relationships'
has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_rooms, source: :room # the actual rooms a user favorites
```

**room.rb**

```
has_many :favorite_rooms # just the 'relationships'
has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_rooms, source: :user # the actual users favoriting a room
```

Comment: current_user ist automatically defined by the devise gem

Comment: So you want the code to work for an unauthorized user. But you use `current_user`. What is the idea? Can you just wrap this code to `if current_user`?

Comment: I want that the visitor is able to see the favorite link and if they click on the favorite link they are going to be redirected to the registration page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `current_user` is defined.
Try this code

```
<% if current_user && current_user.favorites.exists(@room) %>
  # your if
<% else %>
  # your else
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks allot! That solved the issue now I have to figure out how to make it redirect_to login_path if the user is not logged in... do you have any hints what I should change in the rooms controller in order to make this work?

Comment: I am on my way home. I will try to help you in about an hour.

Comment: Thanks allot Aleksey! ;)

Comment: With devise you can add `before_action :authenticate_user!` to be sure that only authenticated user can access an action (you can specify exact action names in `before_action`).